# Adding DOJO Toolkit to an existing worklight project

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I need to add DOJO components to my worklight app. I didn't select the "Dojo toolkit" checkbox while creating the hybrid project. How can I add DOJO toolkit to an existing worklight hybrid project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you project is just starting, you might as well just create a new project and application -- using the Dojo wizard -- and simply copy over your JS/CSS/HTML (note the template of the HTML, you'll need to copy snippets, not the whole thing).

I think the above would be infinitely easier.

The other way is to create another project and application - using the Dojo wizard - and do the opposite - copy the JS/HTML template from that project, to yours...

Comment: My project is more than a month old. so I think the second approach can be applied.